# login to wordpress with jquery ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, authentication

I'm trying to create a seperate login page for a Wordpress project.  The method of this login is to send the login to the wp-login.php via jquery ajax.

```
var dataString ='log="'+$('#user_login').val()+'&pwd='+$('#user_pass').val()+'"&redirect_to=&testcookie=1&wp-submit=Log+In';

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "agents/wp-login.php",
    data: dataString,
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mworkFile.php",
            data: { task: "FirstLoad"}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            $('#masterdiv').html(msg);
            lsoff();
        });
    });
    });
```

I'm using mworkfile to check if the user is logged in but I can't make it that far.  I think I might be missing something in the URL (dataString).  I have verified that the data is getting to /wp-login.php and the username and pass are correct.  When I try to pass this info via chrome it just sends me back to the login screen again.  This is the URL I tried.
www.website.com/agents/wp-login.php?log=TheUsername&pwd=ThePW&redirect_to=&testcookie=1&wp-submit=Log In.